# Use Querypath to directly access an ID

Tags: php, querypath

Hi pretty basic question that I'm surprised wasn't already asked here.

Is it possible to directly get an element based on an id, using Querypath?

Currently, the way I do it is

```
$qp = htmlqp('../index.php');
foreach ($qp->find('img') as $key) {

    if ($key -> attr('id') === "$picID") {
        $src = $key -> attr('src', $src) -> writeHTML("../indextest.php");
    }
}
```

however this does not seem to be the most efficient method as it loops through every image each time, when it could just access the ID directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://api.querypath.org/docs/_c_s_s_reference.html).

It's just

```
$qp->find('#my-ID');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use getElementById function of XPath http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php